# How can I control Bootstrap 4 modal state in React without jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I develop a PHP web app. The UI is built with Twig templates.

I've started to add some new (and replace some existing) forms with ReactJS components. I like the approach and I am happy with the results.

The application uses Bootstrap 4. A couple of the ReactJS components wrap/use the Bootstrap 4 modal.

I show/hide the modals with JQuery inside the React components. I can't work out any other way of doing it.

```
$("#myModal").modal('show');
```

I know you're supposed to avoid JQuery in React, but is there another way of opening/closing the modals without JQuery? A couple of lines of JQuery per component seems like the simplest approach.

I tried to open close the modals by setting state and then applying styles, but it doesn't work because I still need to set styles on the 'parent' body outside the React component.

Comment: The issue is most likely you are using vanilla Bootstrap ..  You should be using the [React BootStrap Modal Components](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/) --  But first you need to be using [React Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction)

Answer (score 0):

It's better to avoid jQuery in React Components.
For your bootstrap modals, you can convert them to [ReactBootStrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) components.

You can achieve the same thing with this one as well.

Moreover you can use ref={refName} on the modal and access the DOM element for the modal and use the .modal() function provided by Bootstrap to show/hide the modal.

Like below:

```
const modalRef = useRef(null);

const handleShowModal = () => {
  $(modalRef.current).modal('show');
};
const handleHideModal = () => {
  $(modalRef.current).modal('hide');
};
```

The Modal Div should be `<div ref={modalRef}` like this.

Comment: Sorry for being ambiguous. I was trying to mean if he still insists to use the legacy Code, he can use the second approach.